# Web API optional parameters from querystring returning request is missing body

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I'm attempting to build a route similar to this:

/accounts/{accountId}/stuff/?stuffAfterDate=2015-04-19T12%3A30%3A00

that you can also call as

/accounts/{accountId}/stuff

to return everything. So stuffAfterDate is a filter.

My web API action looks like

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("accounts/{accountId}/stuff")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetStuffForAccount(int accountId, DateTime? stuffAfterDate = null)
```

But when I go to /accounts/1/stuff it returns "Request is missing body"

Everything I've found on Stack Overflow or online just seems to indicate that all you need to do is make the parameter nullable with a default value of null, but that doesn't work. I've also tried creating a normal route table entry but I can't seem to get that to work either. I've also tried adding [FromUri] to the stuffAfterDate value.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix rest style with query string. 
You can also achieve this by only rest like below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("accounts/{accountId}/stuff/{stuffAfterDate:datetime?}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetStuffForAccount(int accountId, DateTime? stuffAfterDate = null)
```

You can try this by another way:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("accounts/{accountId}/stuff/")]
public IHttpActionResult GetStuffForAccount(int accountId)
{
  var queryString = this.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

  var p1Val = queryString.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == "stuffAfterDate").Value;
  DateTime stuffAfterDate = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p1Val)) ?  null : DateTime.ParseExact(p1Val, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


  //do your remaining code here
}
```

Please let me know, is this works for you.

Comment: In REST style the URL is meant to represent a resource right? My understanding is that if you then want to filter you should use the querystring, so I don't think the first one fits with REST conventions (though debating REST is my least favourite thing to do :))

The second one will work, but I was hoping that the web API model binder would do that for me, as I believe it should. I use Swashbuckle/Swagger for API docs and the querystring param wont show up if I do the second one so I was hoping for a better way

Comment: You can refer this link for model binder when it works: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx